# ISP broadband user Authentication

Tags: networking, isp, broadband, packet, radius

How does an ISP authenticate a broadband user via its radius server or any other methods. Will it would be possible for me to locate this server eg- packet capture,by halfbridge mode, ip tracert?

Is this server my Broadband Gateway (shown in the Router WAN page)

Thank you for your time

Answer (score -1):

In the UK, most smaller retail ISPs buy services from BT Wholesale's backbone instead of buying services directly from Openreach (the local access network provider) and having to provide their own backbone and BRAS equipment.

Most backbone network providers, including BT Wholesale use PPPoE. Some like Sky use IPoE. Sky use DHCP and option 61 MAC address of the router to authenticate the customer, perhaps option 82 to verify the line. Option 82 depends on the vendor and contains VLAN information (giving the opportunity to have 1 CVLAN per end user line), or the ingress interface ID, or both, and is inserted by the DHCP relay agent on the DSLAM switch. The DHCP server converts these to radius attributes and makes an Access-Request before assigning an IP. The server is on the BRAS, and IPoE sessions are terminated here rather than the ISP LNS, meaning it is the responsibility of the wholesale provider that buys local access services from Openreach to assign IPs, contacting their own or perhaps the ISPs DHCP server if TalkTalk had ISP customers and then tunnel all packets from these IPs to the ISP LNS.

For end users using BT Wholesale based ISPs, the username is bthomehub@btinternet.com with no password and VLAN 101, which is Openreach's VLAN for their customers GEA cablelink data. This means it is using PADI authentication instead of just CHAP. The DSLAM switch has a PPPoE relay agent, which inserts the Vendor–Specific circuit-ID tag based on the ingress port on the DSLAM into the PPPoE PADI packets as they traverse to the BRAS's PPPoE server. BT Wholesale have their own BRASes, as do Sky and TalkTalk, but ISPs that buy from BT Wholesale do not.

The PPPoE server is configured to send the circuit ID as radius attribute 87 (NAS-Port-ID)  to the Radius server in an Access-Request in response to the CHAP challenge response from the client, along with the CHAP username. The Circuit-ID contains the MAC or serial number of the DSLAM, and the ingress interface ID. In the Access-Accept there will be the IP of the ISP's LNS and the L2TP TunnelID. It seems unlikely to me that the DSLAM circuit ID would be on the ISP's radius server, so this is likely all handled at the BRAS. Once the tunnel is set up, the CHAP username and password is what is passed on to the LNS and verified on the ISP's radius on or separate to the LNS. The ISP then assigns an IP using IPCP from an IP pool or an IP specific to a subscriber taken from from the radius server in the Access-Accept. I would guess that the tunnel is probably IP over PPP over L2TPv3 over IP over MPLS over Ethernet over DWDM.